# DateTime.TryParse fails for perfectly valid dates

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I've read this string from a file: `23/07/1998`. This is a perfectly valid date string. It has no ambiguity, given those numbers there (appears) to be only one possible way to parse it.

`DateTime.TryParse`, on the other hand, tells me its invalid. I suspect this is due to my culture settings.

TryParse has variations that are rather complex, so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to parse this with "dd/MM/yyyy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim iString As String = "01/12/1998"
Dim oDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
MsgBox(oDate.ToString())
```

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz please mark it as an answer to move it off the queue of unanswered questions

Comment: While this may answer his question it would've been better to include an explanation about what caused the problem and why your answer fixes it (i.e. what's the difference between `Parse` and `ParseExact`). _"Code only"_-answers are generally frowned upon as they usually only contribute to solving the problem, without _**teaching**_ the OP or other readers anything.

Answer (score 4):

TryParse doesn't know if your date is MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy.  It's obvious to the observer only because we can deduce from the fact that there is no month 23.  But it wouldn't know what 02/03/1998 was.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Will tell it which format to use.

Comment: Short and concise answer, with a very good explanation! +1 -- **NOTE TO OP:** Both answers so far have mentioned `ParseExact()`, but there is also [**`TryParseExact()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) (although it has an even more annoying syntax ;)

Comment: Oddly, the macOS/Unix/Linux version of this call handles this without specifying the format. It also handles things like "tomorrow" and "next tuesday". It's a bit surprising to see the .net version is so primitive in comparison given it's freeze date is something like two decades later.

Answer (score 0):

Like already [mentioned by dwilliss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46595383) the regular `DateTime.TryParse()` method cannot distinguish between `dd/MM` and `MM/dd`, and operates only on a standard set of date time formats. To specify a different format use either [**`DateTime.ParseExact()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) or [**`DateTime.TryParseExact()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want a less annoying syntax you can create an [**extension method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods) wrapping the [**`DateTime.TryParseExact()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function TryParseDate(ByVal Input As String, ByVal Format As String, <Out()> ByRef Result As DateTime) As Boolean
        Return DateTime.TryParseExact(Input, Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, Result)
    End Function
End Module
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
Dim DateString As String = "23/07/1998"
Dim ResultDate As DateTime = Nothing

If DateString.TryParseDate("dd/MM/yyyy", ResultDate) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Success: " & ResultDate.ToString())
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Input was not a valid date!")
End If
```